# Eclipse IDE 2022-06, how to change template when create new JSP file?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, java-ee-5

I am using Eclipse IDE 2022-06 , Java/JDK 1.6, Windows 10 pro x64, Spring 2.5.6 .

[image]

I need encoding `UTF-8` by default, not `ISO-8859-1`. I don't want edit many files, many time manually. How to change template when create new JSP file?

Comment: The encoding for a new JSP file can be configured in the preferences _Web > JSP Files_. In the _New JSP File_ dialog click _Next_ to choose a template or click the _JSP Templates_ link to go where you can change the template.

Comment: You can post your answer, I will accept it. How to set value for `${encoding}` ?

Answer (score 2):

In the ***New JSP File* dialog click *Next***

- to **choose a template** or
- click the ***JSP Templates* link** to go to the preferences *Web > JSP Files > Editor > Templates* where you can **change the template for JSP**.

By default, in the JSP templates the variable **`${encoding}`** is used which can be configured in the **preferences *Web > JSP Files***.

[image]

[image]

sample result

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in a Dynamic Web Project in eclipse IDE for web development, then click the "Window" menu tab, then "Preferences", then the Preferences window comes up, then in the navigation column (left), click "Web" > "Editor" > "Templates". Then, click on the the "New" template you want to change and click the "Edit" button. The window that allows you to change the tags comes up. Make the changes, then click OK, and then click "Apply and Close" and it's done.
[image]